# How to take down ASTs in COD:Advanced Warfare?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

Every time I come across an AST, I end up using almost all my grenades and a lot of ammo to take it down. Is there any effective method to take down an AST, like a weakspot or something?

Comment: This thread says to grapple them from behind: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/CodAW/comments/2mfnqv/is_this_a_well_known_way_to_kill_the_big_mechsuit/

Comment: @recognizer it is possible to do that only in the mission "Throttle" where you have a grapple in your exo suit.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to smart grenade them or emp spam, ive done that before and killed them with about all of emp or smarts, frags also work.